# Crud actions on input set - react+flux+alt+es6

Tags: reactjs, reactjs-flux

I am new to react.In my application I have to perform crud action on inputset(contains one selectbox and textarea) within form.Form loads with one inputset with default values.

**Actions**

1. Onchange of inputset text it should update state if not it should
   store with default values.
2. OnAdd it should check previous element has not empty description.
3. Paricular inputSet should be removed and on clearing description
   also it should remove that inputSet

**Image:**
[image]

**Code:**

Item

```
import React from 'react';
import { Input, Button, Glyphicon } from 'react-bootstrap';

export default class TextBoxesSet extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  _onRemoveName = () => {
    console.log('remove');
  }
  static getPropsFromStores() {
    return {language: 'en', description: ''};
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div >
        <div className="">
          <Input type="select" placeholder="select" wrapperClassName="col-xs-4"
          value={this.props.language} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, 'language')} >
            <option value="en">en</option>
            <option value="de">de</option>
          </Input>
        </div>
        <div className="col-md-7">
          <Input type="textarea" wrapperClassName="col-xs-12" value={this.props.description}
          onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, 'description')} />
        </div>
        <div className="col-md-1">
          <Button bsSize="small"><Glyphicon glyph="remove" onClick={this._onRemoveName} /></Button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
  handleChange(name, e) {
    const obj = {};
    obj[name] = e.target.value;
    this.setState(obj);
    if (this.state.language !== undefined && this.state.description !== undefined) {
      this.props.handleChange('name', this.state);
    }
  }
}
TextBoxesSet.propTypes = {
  language: React.PropTypes.string,
  description: React.PropTypes.string,
  handleChange: React.PropTypes.func
};
```

List

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button, Glyphicon } from 'react-bootstrap';
// import TextBoxStore from 'stores/textBoxStore';
import TextBoxesSet from './descriptionTextBoxes';

export default class TextBoxesSetList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  _onAddName = (label) => {
    if (this.state) {
      this.state[label].length++;
      React.render(<TextBoxesSet labelName="name" language="de" handleChange={this.handleTextBoxSetChange}/>, document.getElementById('another'));
    }
  }
  _onRemoveName = () => {
    console.log('remove');
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div >
        <ul >
          <TextBoxesSet label={this.props.labelName} handleChange={this.props.handleChange}/>
        </ul>
        <div className="col-md-1">
          <Button bsSize="small"><Glyphicon glyph="plus" onClick={this._onAddName} /></Button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
 }
TextBoxesSetList.propTypes = {
  newItem: React.PropTypes.string,
  list: React.PropTypes.array,
  labelName: React.PropTypes.string,
  handleChange: React.PropTypes.func
};
```

Form

```
import React from 'react';
import { Input, Button, Glyphicon, ButtonToolbar } from 'react-bootstrap';
import AttributeSectionStore from 'stores/attributeSection/AttributeSectionStore';
import TextBoxesSetList from '../TextBoxesList';
import styles from 'scss/_common';

export default class Name extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleTextBoxSetChange = this.handleTextBoxSetChange.bind(this);
  }
  _onCreate = () => {
    console.log('___________', this.state);
  }
  static getPropsFromStores() {
    return AttributeSectionStore.getState();
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className={styles.mainheader}>
          <h2 >New Form</h2>
        </div>
        <div className="col-md-9">
        <form className="form-horizontal">
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-xs-2">
              <label className="">Name</label>
            </div>
            <div className="col-md-6">
              <TextBoxesSetList labelName="name" handleChange={this.handleTextBoxSetChange}/>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
  handleChange(name, e) {
    const change = {};
    change[name] = e.target.value;
    this.setState(change);
  }
  handleTextBoxSetChange(label, obj) {
    const change = {};
    if (this.state[label] === undefined) {
      console.log('--------------------');
      change[label] = [];
      change[label].push(obj);
    }
    this.setState(change);
  }
}

Name.propTypes = {
    name: React.PropTypes.arrayOf(React.PropTypes.object)
};
```

Please help me in solving?